# Can I visit the USA and come back to Canada with expired Canadian visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

I am currently in Canada on a work permit. My work requires me to visit the US frequently and I have been there multiple times. Recently my Canadian visa has expired I need to visit the US again. Can I visit the US with my expired Canadian visa and come back to Canada?

Comment: For clarity, you have a current/valid Canadian Work Permit *and* a (now expired) Tourist Visa or similar?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are allowed to travel to Canada using a valid work (or student) permit instead of a visa, provided you have only gone to the USA or St. Pierre and Miquelon.

Timatic (the database which airlines use to verify that your travel documents are sufficient for travel) states, in relevant part:

> Passengers with a valid student or work permit are allowed
>     to return to Canada from the USA or St. Pierre and Miquelon
>     without obtaining a new visa, if  they have not left the USA
>     or St. Pierre and Miquelon to a third country and are
>     returning within the period of entry authorized (expiry date
>     of student or work permit) or within 6 months of original
>     entry stamp.

Comment: I'm not sure the "Yes" is correct, as the OP has not revealed or confirmed that their proposed re-entry into Canada will occur "...within 6 months of original entry stamp."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Entry stamp is only for visitors who entered without being given a visitor record or other status document. Study or work permit holders can enter Canada without visa subsequent to visits to US (and only US/StPM) as long as the permit is valid. I should note however not all airline agents are well-trained and one may encounter difficulty and must be prepared to escalate (non-budget AC/WS usually are better on subtlties of Canadian regulations).